# joining 2 tables with where clause

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables like these

TABLE 1

```
**user_id**       **text**
    1         test
    1         test 
    2         test
    2         test
    3         test
```

TABLE 2

```
**user_id**   **status**
1            1
2            0
3            0
```

how can i select users whose status is 1 from TABLE 1 ?

Thanks

Comment: you should probably have put just one ounce of effort in to your own query...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.user_id
FROM `TABLE 1` t1
INNER JOIN `TABLE 2` t2 ON t1.user_id=t2.user_id
WHERE t2.status=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.user_id, t1.text FROM table1 t1, table t2
WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id
    AND t2.status = '1';
```

Hope it helps.